# For loop drawing from multiple files

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am quite new to Unix and would like to convert a script I previously had in R. For this I have three different files (of equal lengths) with different variants of file names. I would like to iterate through all three files line by line taking one line from each. However I am not sure how to incorporate more than one variable into a for loop.

```
module load bbtools 

for i in fna and j in fna2 and k in fna.prefix; 
do 
rename.sh -Xmx20g in=",${i}," out=",${j}" prefix=",${k}"
done
```

Is there any way I can run this directly without calling on a R script?

Comment: for me it is not clear what "something like this" means. Can you tell us what `rename.sh` is doing? Also, you have a syntax error, the single quote isn't closed.

Comment: Hi I have updated the case hopefully it makes it more clear. rename.sh it taking an input file(in=",${i},), adding the same prefix to each line (prefix=",${k}") and then creating a renames output file (out=",${j}"). I want to create something where for the first iteration of the loop, it will draw from line 1 of each file.

Comment: R and sh/bash have completely different syntax.   You can't run an R script in a shell interpreter.  You need to either re-write the script, using valid shell syntax.  Or, much easier, you can run the R script from the shell (or in a shell script).

Comment: in shell, a for loop can only iterate one variable at a time.    You can nest for loops, however.   e.g. `for i in $(<fna); do for j in $(<fna2); do for k in $(<fna.prefix); do rename.sh ....... ; done; done; done`

Comment: However, that isn't going to do what you want.   You need to read each file into 3 separate arrays, and then iterate **once** over the array elements.  You probably also want to check that the number of elements in each array is the same.   You could use a for loop to read in each file, but it's better to use `mapfile`.   e.g. `mapfile a < fna; mapfile b < fna2; mapfile c < fna.prefix`.   Then, later, something like:  `for i in $(seq 0 $((${#a[@]}-1))) ; do rename.sh -Xmx20g in=",${a[i]}," out=",${b[i]}" prefix=",${c[i]}" ; done`

Comment: On second thoughts, it would be simpler to use `mapfile`'s `-O` option to set the origin of the array to 1 instead of the default of 0.  e.g. `mapfile -O 1 a < fna`.  That would make the final loop simpler, because there's no need to do any calculations.  `for i in $(seq 1 "${#a[@]}") ; do ... ; done`

Comment: Thank you so much! The second option worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your 3 files into 3 separate arrays, and then iterate over them **once**.  It would also be a good idea to check that the arrays are the same length.

`bash` has a built-in function called `mapfile` for reading text files into an array.  While there are options to change the default behaviour of `mapfile`, by default, each line of the input file is loaded into an array element.  Also by default, `maparray` uses 0 as the origin of the array, but you can override that with the `-O` option (e.g. `-O 1` to start the array from 1 instead of 0).

Run `help mapfile` in bash, or search the bash man page for details on mapfile.

For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# load the three files into arrays a, b, and c.
mapfile -t -O 1 a < fna
mapfile -t -O 1 b < fna2
mapfile -t -O 1 c < fna.prefix

# check if they're the same length    
if [ "${#a[@]}" != "${#b[@]}" ] || [ "${#a[@]}" != "${#c[@]}" ]; then
  echo "input files are not the same length"
  exit 1
fi

# do something with them, iterating from 1 to the length of array a.    
for i in $(seq 1 "${#a[@]}"); do
  rename.sh -Xmx20g in=",${a[i]}," out=",${b[i]}" prefix=",${c[i]}"
done
```

Note: if the 3 files are huge, millions or billions of lines each, this would use an unfeasible amount of memory.   Better to use a language that makes it easy to open 3 files at once and read in one line from each file for each iteration of the loop. e.g. awk, perl, python, C, etc.  Even R.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `paste` command. For files:

a.txt

```
1
2
3
```

b.txt

```
a
b
c
```

c.txt

```
z
x
y
```

A sample command output is:

```
$ paste -d, a.txt b.txt c.txt
1,x,a
2,y,b
3,z,c
```

You can then pipe it (with the right separator, the one you use in the `paste` command):

```
paste -d, a.txt b.txt c.txt | while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3; do
    # do your task with $f1 $f2 $3
done
```